# How do I visualize the output of my regressive type CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am running a CNN of a regressive type which inputs and outputs images of different dimensions (so not a an Image-segmentation problem) based on a dataset of samples and corresponding labels. As a result the last dense layer of my network has the height and width of the labels multiplied together. Now, I have been training the network for a while now and I wanted to see what the images looked like so to see how good or bad my model is. Is there a function that provides me with this option or do I have to hard-code it? How do I do it? 
Down below is attached the code of my network and the network summary as well.

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 54, 1755, 4)       20

---

activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 54, 1755, 4)       0

---

max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 18, 585, 4)        0

---

batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 18, 585, 4)        16

---

conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 17, 584, 8)        136

---

activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 17, 584, 8)        0

---

max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 292, 8)         0

---

batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 8, 292, 8)         32

---

conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 7, 291, 16)        528

---

activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 7, 291, 16)        0

---

max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 3, 145, 16)        0

---

batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 3, 145, 16)        64

---

conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 144, 32)        2080

---

activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 2, 144, 32)        0

---

max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 1, 72, 32)         0

---

batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 1, 72, 32)         128

---

flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 2304)              0

---

dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 2304)              0

---

dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 19316)             44523380

---

activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 19316)             0

=================================================================

Total params: 44,526,384
Trainable params: 44,526,264
Non-trainable params: 120

---

Thanks in advance!

```
def generator(data_arr, batch_size = 10):

num = len(data_arr) 
num = int(num/batch_size)

# Loop forever so the generator never terminates
while True: 

    for offset in range(0, num):

        batch_samples = (data_arr[offset*batch_size:(offset+1)*batch_size])

        samples = []
        labels = []

        for batch_sample in batch_samples:

            samples.append(batch_sample[0])
            labels.append((np.array(batch_sample[1].flatten())).transpose())

        X_ = np.array(samples)
        Y_ = np.array(labels)

        X_ = X_[:, :, :, newaxis]

        yield (X_, Y_)

# compile and train the model using the generator function
train_generator = generator(training_data, batch_size = 10)
validation_generator = generator(val_data, batch_size = 10)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(4, (2, 2), input_shape = (55, 1756, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(8, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(19316))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

def nrmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred - 
y_true)))/(2)

def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred - y_true), 
axis=-1))

model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error',
             optimizer = 'adam',
             metrics = [rmse, nrmse])

model.summary()
```

Comment: what are you asking for..have you already trained your model and asking for how to test it.. or you want to visualize the metrics of trained model..pl be more specific

Comment: Yes, I don't understand what you are asking, is it either function to visualize the image (like imshow), or just how to reshape the output back to an image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply @Matias Valdenegro. As you commented, I meant how given my model do I reshape the output back to an image. Do I just use the reshape() function? What do I pass as argument though? And were in the code should I place it ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, @geekzeus. As commented above I meant more how to reshape the output to an image. I did train and test my model and am also able to analyze the metrics, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: You need to add more information about your output vector. More specifically you GT labels and how where they created and what do they mean? (How did you end up with an output vector of 19316 parameters?)

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment @Mark.F. What do you mean when you say "you GT labels"? The output vector is of 19316 because the output image has dimensions 11,1756; multiplying them together gives 19316.

Comment: I meant "your GT labels", where GT stands for Ground Truth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the output of your model should represent the grayscale values of the pixels of an image with the dimensions (11,1756).

There is no need to hard-code a special function, you can simply use the standard reshape() function on the output of the model.

```
images = y_pred.reshape((-1, 11, 1756))
```

> You are probably already doing that when creating the vectors for the
>   y_true parameters that you are using during training (I assume that
>   the shape of the Ground Truth y_true variable is originally (11,
>   1756), and you reshape it to a single column vector form).